# Pytorch GPU memory keeps increasing with every batch

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pytorch

I'm training a CNN model on images. Initially, I was training on image patches of size `(256, 256)` and everything was fine. Then I changed my dataloader to load full HD images `(1080, 1920)` and I was cropping the images after some processing. In this case, the GPU memory keeps increasing with every batch. Why is this happening?

PS: While tracking losses, I'm doing `loss.detach().item()` so that loss is not retained in the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/gpu-memory-consumption-increases-while-training/2770/3?u=nagabhushansn95), deleting the input, output and loss data helped.

Additionally, I had the data as a dictionary. Just deleting the dictionary isn't sufficient. I had to iterate over the dict elements and delete all of them.